# What strategy is thoughtful to evaluate WebGl-Based APIs?

Tags: webgl

Since there are lot of high level APIs , libraries and Frameworks available for webGL for developing 3D web applications, I want to select the best (sorry this is bit straightforward) to implement a particular model (which isn't Game oriented) on web. I'm confused how to approach for my work, The criteria I want to use for evaluation is:

pickable objects, easily defined geometry and corresponding texture, multi-camera rendering, possible to incorporate GSLS implementations, type of buffers available.

I can't experiment and judge myself a framework by developing every single demo application in every framework due to time constraint. Is there any particular way to read the documentation for available APIs which mention all these. Moreover, the problem is every framework says they are good in some part and how to overcome this to justify single framework among all those available in net world.

A suggestion would suffice my research...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have Maya at hand then www.inka3d.com is easy in terms of defining geometry and texture (because you do it with Maya and your favorite image editor) and you get pickable objects. For shaders you can't use glsl but have to use Maya's node based shader editor.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I do have one more question, How can I evaluate the frameworks based on:
1. Most actively developed
2. Documentation
3. Community Support (like forums, active discussions)
4. Wide variety of examples

I need to develop an application (not a gaming one), like visualizing the 3D model, in selected framework. I wish you could guide me somehow.